# Count car by region in mongo DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to do a count car by region using NodeJS and expose as a rest API.

```
app.get('/countcarbyregion', function(req, res){
  db.collection('collection').aggregate({"$group":{"_id":"$region", "sum":{"$cartype":1}}}).toArray(function(err, results) {
  res.send(results);
  })
  res.set({
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
  });
});
```

Sample JSON doc:

```
{"_id":"5b506dccc00e755288ceaec6","cartype":"Mercedes Benz E Class E250 CDI Avantgarde (2013) in Mumbai","URL":"Null","price":2700000,"region":"Mumbai","Man_year":2013}
```

I tried to do this but it didn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you add sample document(JSON)?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/r7MfLsuu1Fi). The syntax of the `aggregate()` method can be a little tricky: it takes a [pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/index.html) of stages as opposed to a single matching query like `find()`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$region",
      numOfCars: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query:

```
db.collection('collection').aggregate([{$group: {_id: "$region", sum: {$sum: 1}}}])
```